# How to do vector sum more elegantly instead of using '+' operator

Tags: r, vector

I have bunch of vector that needed to vector sum one to another. I am seeking more elegant solution for vector adding instead of using '+' operator. Does any one know any trick of doing this in more comfortable way. Thanks

Vector:

```
a <- c(1,1,0,2,1,0,1,0,1)
b <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0)
c <- c(0,1,1,0,0,2,1,1,1)
```

I know dummy way of doing this, I am expecting something elegant for doing this

Desired output:

```
out <- c(1,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2)
```

Any elegant way for doing this kind of operation more efficiently?

Comment: Maybe `colSums(rbind(a,b,c))` ?

Comment: How many vectors do you need to add up, maybe my solution might not be the best. As in, we do not want to type all vectors into `rbind(a, b, c, .... z)` ...

Comment: possibly `Reduce("+",list(a,b,c))` ?  (still using the + operator ...)

Comment: @zx8754: the case that if I have very big vector like millions long each, so using '+' operator was not desired. I think your solution is pretty good. I come up another solution based on inspired of yours.

Comment: "I come up another solution " - please share as an answer, you can post answers to your own questions, or suggest edit to my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can put all vectors together using rbind, then use colSums:

```
colSums(rbind(a, b, c))
# [1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2
```

Benchmarking:

```
# bigger input
set.seed(1)
n <- 10^7
a <- runif(n)
b <- runif(n)
c <- runif(n)
d <- runif(n)
e <- runif(n)
f <- runif(n)

# benchmark
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  colSums = colSums(rbind(a, b, c, d, e, f)),
  rowSums = rowSums(cbind(a, b, c, d, e, f)),
  Reduce = base::Reduce("+", list(a, b, c, d, e, f)),
  S4vReduce = S4Vectors::Reduce('+', lapply(list(a, b, c, d, e, f), lengths)),
  JustAdd = a + b + c + d + e + f
)


# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval   cld
#    colSums 408.31052 427.94015 470.27181 461.18763 494.1420 651.3383   100     e
#    rowSums 349.93752 359.15854 408.82652 397.99315 434.1662 569.3575   100    d 
#     Reduce 129.43443 134.55584 183.34432 179.88746 208.0281 339.9345   100  b   
#  S4vReduce 162.90015 166.19150 206.16387 192.73739 212.2146 380.2038   100   c  
#    JustAdd  73.38243  74.00267  92.68309  76.12524  82.7517 282.6101   100 a
```

Comment: And obviously also `rowSums(cbind(a,b,c))`

Answer (score 3):

Using Reduce from S4Vectors:

```
vec.li <- list(a,b,c)
vec.sum <- S4Vectors::Reduce('+', lapply(vec.li, lengths))
```

this solution could fit for the case that adding very big dimension vectors, fast and efficient so far.